# struts 2 multiple select boxes

Tags: jsp, select, tags, struts2, dojo

In my web page I use two select boxes, second one will fill according to the value selected on first select box using ajax (dojo plugin).

```
<s:select label="Select Item"
          name="selectitem"
          headerKey="0"
          headerValue="-- Please Select --" 
          list="itemList"
          required="true"
          onchange="javascript:show_details();"/>


<s:url id="d_url" action="depotFill" /> 

<sx:div id="details"
        href="%{d_url}"
        listenTopics="show_detail"
        formId="depotFix"
        showLoadingText="Loading..."></sx:div>
```

The second select box will be filled using the "depotFill" action and loaded from some other page to the "details" div tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:select headerValue="-- Please Select --"
          name="dest"
          list="unitList"
          headerKey="0"/>
```

This works fine, but now I need to have 5 pairs like this on my web page. Is this means that I'm going to have to create 5 more pages contains secondary select boxes? or is there any way to simplify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[<s:doubleselect />](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/doubleselect.html)**?

Answer (score 0):

The doubleselect will do this for you. It renders a select tag (for the first drop down values), each of which contain a sublist of the options for the second drop down when selected.

[Struts Guide - doubleselect tag ref](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/doubleselect.html)

Comment: can i use it with ajax? dojo support?

Comment: I haven't, but I don't see why not. The tag creates a JavaScript function(s). Implement it, Right Click > View Source, enjoy! Should be able to update its array with AJAX